# C# winform File.Copy from a SaveDialog

Tags: c#

I am attempting to copy a `.txt` from my application directory or some kind an export feature to users desire path and filename using `savedialog` on C# my code is below.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "output.txt";
     using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
     {
         dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt);
         dialog.FilterIndex = 2;
         dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

         if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             File.Copy(directory, Path.GetDirectoryName(dialog.FileName) + dialog.FileName);
         }
     }
}
```

But I am getting an error

> The given path's format is not supported.

I am new with C# and want to understand this error and in addition, I want to set the file name extention default as .txt also, any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Did you notice that you call GetDirectoiryName from the resulting dialog.Filename? Then why you add again the dialog.FileName?

Comment: When you store the target string in an extra variable you can use your debugger and see what goes wrong and why the path is invalid.

Comment: There's a [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) designed for building up paths from fragments, rather than unreliable string concatenation where *you* have to work out whether you've got appropriate path separators in place. Also, as Steve says, unclear why you're trying to do anything with the `FileName` property - there's no way to magically conjure more information out of it than it already contains.

Comment: Before `File.Copy` add `Debug.Print( "{0}", Path.GetDirectoryName(dialog.FileName) + dialog.FileName );` to see your filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to change.
First, of course, is your copy call. This line makes no sense

```
File.Copy(directory, Path.GetDirectoryName(dialog.FileName) + dialog.FileName);
```

dialog.FileName contains already the full file name of your destination file. So there is no need to extract the directory and then add all the path again. Write just

```
File.Copy(directory, dialog.FileName);
```

But this creates a possible error. What if your user doesn't change the destination folder to another directory? You end up writing on the same file you want to read.
So I would add a sanity check like this

```
if(directory == dialog.FileName)
    MessageBox.Show("Copy","Choose a different output folder");
else
    File.Copy(directory, dialog.FileName);
```

Finally, if you want to force the output file to have always the .TXT extension you could add this line to the SaveDialog configuration

```
// Fix also your filter property. The one you have is invalid
dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
dialog.FilterIndex = 0;  // 2 ?? There is no index 2 in your filter string
dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

// Force the .TXT extension
dialog.AddExtension = true;
```